# VLC: transition straight to fullscreen (no transition effect)

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player

When I use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to get VLC into fullscreen while running a video, there's a transition effect (the video expands diagonally until it's fullscreen). [Incidentally, this generally causes the currently-playing frame to expand, which takes some time, so I see an individual frame during the expansion, then jump to `current-time + transition time` without seeing the intervening frames].

I can't seem to find the option to get rid of the transition effect. I want to jump straight from small- to full-screen video while playing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I use VLC in Windows.  The key for full screen is just 'F'.  It doesn't do a transition.  Could this be an OSX setting?  I notice that Macs tend to have this blow-up effect when maximizing windows etc.  Sorry I don't know how to disable it, but I'd go into your system settings and find something involving 'user interface animation', 'look and feel', 'performance settings', or 'pointless aesthetics' =)

Comment: Oh, and is there a reason you don't just pause the video, fullscreen, and then resume?

Comment: @paddy because it's 200% more keystrokes... it should work without dumb animations...